# Java OpenGL Texture2d Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, opengl, illegalargumentexception

I'm doing some simple 3d opengl work, just trying to get a 2d texture loaded to display on some of the walls. So far, I loaded the texture correctly(I think), put it in a ByteBuffer, then tried to put it in opengl. I keep getting an illegal argument exception, and I don't understand why. Here is what is printed in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 0, must be at least 676. Because at most 676 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 676 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:230)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.java:2811)
at RPG.Main.setUpGraphics(Main.java:156)
at RPG.Main.main(Main.java:462)
```

Here is the code that i'm trying to load the file with:

```
floorTexture = glGenTextures();
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(new File("res/textures/floor.png"));
    byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
    boolean next = true;
    byte nextByte;
    int i = 0;
    while(next) {
        nextByte = (byte) in.read();
        if(nextByte != 0) {
            data[i] = nextByte;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            next = false;
        }
    }
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    buffer.flip();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)Math.sqrt(buffer.capacity()),    (int)Math.sqrt(buffer.capacity()), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    close(true, e);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    close(true, e);
}
finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            close(true, e);
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on and what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Alright, so I fixed it so that it doesn't have any errors, however it doesn't DISPLAY what is in the texture file. Here's the new code:

```
int texture = glGenTextures();

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imageLocation));

    ColorModel glAlphaColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8, 8, 8 }, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), 4, null);
    BufferedImage texImage = new BufferedImage(glAlphaColorModel, raster, true, new Hashtable());

    // copy the source image into the produced image
    Graphics g = texImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

    // build a byte buffer from the temporary image
    // that be used by OpenGL to produce a texture.
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) texImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
            .getData();

    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length);
    imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    imageBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
    imageBuffer.flip();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The picture is 16 bit. When the program runs, it displays only one solid color, the color of the majority of the picture, however doesn't display any of the features of the picture.

Comment: Why have you divided the width and height by 16?

Comment: Oh. That was me trying just about anything to get it working. It didn't work without dividing by 16, either.

Comment: How are you mapping the texture? I.e have you actually supplied good texture coords?

Comment: Yes. I had it working with a decoder a friend gave me, under the condition that I only used it to test, so I can't use it in my final code. I figured it would be best just to stop using as soon as I could.

Answer (score 2):

There are several probable issues here.

Firstly, you're loading what looks like a PNG file, but you're just loading all the bytes into a buffer and not actually parsing the image format. At best you'll have a header getting in the way of the pixels, and at worst it'll be compressed and look nothing like you expect.

Secondly, you're then working out the dimensions of the image by taking the square-root of the number of bytes, which might be close, if it's a square texture with one-byte per pixel, but will generally just be wrong.

Then you're telling GL to load that texture as a 32-bit texture, at which point it's going to expect 4 bytes for every pixel, which is a lot more than you give it, as you worked out the dimensions as if it were bytes.

You really need to be loading that image with something that understands PNG files, and then getting the image format, dimensions, etc. from that.

Comment: Any suggestions for what should be used to load the png?